# Converting huge .txt file containing JSONString (JSONArray) to Excel using CronJob in java Spring MVC. Getting OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron, large-files

Small files are converted but for huge files I am getting the following exception

```
    Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sw75dao1v61ja2kwuaoa|292bfbfb]-AdminTaskTimer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2022-05-24 00:20:37 WARN  ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread:run 749 - An Error forced the closing of Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sw75dao1v61ja2kwuaoa|292bfbfb]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]. Will attempt to reconstruct, but this might mean that something bad is happening.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have a 240MB .txt file which I am trying to convert to excel using the following code in CronJob

> package samplepackage.cron;
>
> ```
> import java.io.BufferedReader;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.FileReader;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.math.BigDecimal;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.Date;
> import java.util.List;
>
> import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
> import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
> import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
> import org.json.JSONArray;
> import org.json.JSONObject;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
> import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
> import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> import com.ril.asp.gstasp.utils.GSTRUtils;
> import com.ril.asp.gstasp.wrapper.LogWrapper;
>
> @Component
> @Configuration
> @EnableScheduling
> public class CronJobGstr2b {
>
>   @Autowired
>   private GSTRUtil gstrUtil;
>   
>   @Scheduled(cron = "*/120 * * * * *")
>   public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() throws IOException {
>
>       long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
>       LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
>
>       File folder = new File(gstrUtils.getPropertyValue("GSTR2B_FILES"));
>       File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
>
>       if (listOfFiles.length != 0) {
>
>           for (File file : listOfFiles) {
>               if (file.isFile()) {
>                   LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, file.getName());
>                   String fileName = file.getName();
>
>
>                   if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
>
>                       if (fileName.contains("-done")) {
>                           LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "Excel already created");
>                       } else {
>
>                           String[] arrOfStr = fileName.split("_", 6);
>
>                           String gstin = arrOfStr[0];
>                           String userId = arrOfStr[1];
>                           String period = arrOfStr[2];
>                           String section = arrOfStr[3];
>                           String recordsCount = arrOfStr[4];
>
>                           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
>                                   new FileReader(gstrUtils.getPropertyValue("GSTR2B_FILES")+ fileName));
>                           String currentLine = reader.readLine();
>                           reader.close();
>                           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(currentLine);
>                           jsonArray.length();
>
>                           String[] headers = null;
>
>                           Object[] ObjData = null;
>
>                           List<Object[]> listData = new ArrayList<>();
>
>                           String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
>
>                           String xlsxFileName = "";
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("B2B")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR1/5  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR1/5 of supplier",
>                                       "Invoice Number", "Invoice Type", "Invoice Value", "Place of supply",
>                                       "Supply attracts reverse charge", "ITC Availability",
>                                       "Reason for ITC Unavailability", "Applicable % of tax rate", "Item Number",
>                                       "Tax Rate", "Total Taxable value", "IGST Amount as per invoice",
>                                       "CGST Amount as per invoice", "SGST Amount as per invoice",
>                                       "CESS Amount as per invoice" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B B2B" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("CDNR")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR1/5  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR1/5 of supplier",
>                                       "Note Number", "Note Type", "Note Supply Type", "Note Date(dd-mm-yyyy)",
>                                       "Note Value", "Place of supply", "Supply Attracts Reverse Charge",
>                                       "ITC Availability", "Reason for ITC Unavailability", "Applicable % of tax rate",
>                                       "Item Number", "Tax Rate", "Total Taxable Value", "Integrated Tax Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "Central Tax Amount  (Rs.)", "State Tax/ UT Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "Cess Amount (Rs.)" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B CDN" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("B2BA")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR1/5  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR1/5 of supplier",
>                                       "Orignal Invoice Number ", "Orignal Invoice Date (dd-mm-yyyy)  ",
>                                       "Invoice Number", "Invoice Type", "Invoice Date", "Invoice Value(Rs.) ",
>                                       "Place of Supply (State Code) ", "Supply attracts reverse charge",
>                                       "ITC Availability", "Reason for ITC Unavailability", "Applicable % of tax rate",
>                                       "Item Number", "Tax Rate", "Total Taxable value", "Integrated Tax Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "Central Tax Amount (Rs.)", "State Tax/Union Territory Tax Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "CESS Amount (Rs.)" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B B2BA Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("CDNRA")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR1/5  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR1/5 of supplier",
>                                       "Original Note Number", "Original Note Date", "Original Note Type",
>                                       "Note Number", "Note Type", "Note Supply Type", "Note Date", "Note Value",
>                                       "Place of s upply", "Supply attracts Reverse Charge", "ITC Availability",
>                                       "Reason for ITC Unavailability", "Applicable % of tax rate", "Item Number",
>                                       "Tax Value", "Total Taxable value", "Integrated Tax Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "Central Tax Amount  (Rs.)", "State Tax/ UT Amount (Rs.)",
>                                       "Cess Amount (Rs.)" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B CDNA Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("ISD")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR6  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR6 of supplier",
>                                       "ISD Document Type", "ISD Document Number", "ISD Document Date",
>                                       "Original Invoice Number", "Original Invoice date",
>                                       "Integrated Tax Amount (Rs.)", "Central Tax Amount  (Rs.)",
>                                       "State Tax/ UT Amount (Rs.)", "Cess Amount (Rs.)", "Eligible for ITC" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B ISD Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("ISDA")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "GSTIN of the Supplier", "Trade/Legal name of the supplier",
>                                       "Date of filing GSTR6  of supplier", "Filing period of GSTR6 of supplier",
>                                       "Original ISD Document Type", "Original ISD Document Number",
>                                       "Original ISD Document Date", "ISD Document Type", "ISD Document Number",
>                                       "ISD Document Date", "Original Invoice Number", "Original Invoice date",
>                                       "Integrated Tax Amount (Rs.)", "Central Tax Amount  (Rs.)",
>                                       "State Tax/ UT Amount (Rs.)", "Cess Amount (Rs.)", "Eligible for ITC" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B ISDA Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("IMPG")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "ICEGATE Reference Date", "Received Date in the GST System",
>                                       "Port Code", "Bill of Entry Number", "Bill of Entry Date", "Is Amended",
>                                       "Total Taxable value", "Total IGST amount", "Total Cess Amount" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B IMPG Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (section.equalsIgnoreCase("IMPGSEZ")) {
>
>                               headers = new String[] { "ICEGATE Reference Date", "Received Date in the GST System",
>                                       "Port Code", "Bill of Entry Number", "Bill of Entry Date", "Is Amended",
>                                       "Total Taxable value", "Total IGST amount", "Total Cess Amount" };
>
>                               xlsxFileName = gstin + "_" + "GSTR2B IMPGSEZ Data" + "_" + period + "_" + timeStamp;
>
>                           }
>
>                           if (jsonArray instanceof JSONArray) {
>                               for (int x1 = 0; x1 < jsonArray.length(); x1++) {
>                                   JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x1);
>                                   if (jsonObj1.has("error_desc") || jsonObj1.has("error_grp")
>                                           || jsonObj1.has("error_code")) {
>                                   } else {
>                                       if (jsonObj1.has("gstn")) {
>
>                                           if (jsonObj1.get("gstn") instanceof JSONObject) {
>
>                                               JSONObject jsonObjDocData = jsonObj1.getJSONObject("gstn");
> //                                 LogWrapper.info(GSTR2PreReconServiceImpl.class, "||||||||reached here in code||||||||||");
>
>                                               if (jsonObjDocData.has("b2b")) {
>
>                                                   if (jsonObjDocData.has("b2b")
>                                                           && jsonObjDocData.get("b2b") instanceof JSONObject) {
>
>                                                       JSONObject jobj = jsonObjDocData.getJSONObject("b2b");
>
>                                                       double cess;
>
>                                                       double txval;
>
>                                                       double cgst;
>
>                                                       double igst;
>
>                                                       double sgst;
>
>                                                       double rt;
>
>                                                       double num;
>
>                                                       String ctin = "";
>                                                       String trdnm = "";
>                                                       String supfildt = "";
>                                                       String supprd = "";
>
>                                                       if (jobj.has("ctin")) {
>
>                                                           ctin = jobj.getString("ctin");
>
>                                                       }
>                                                       if (jobj.has("trdnm")) {
>
>                                                           trdnm = jobj.getString("trdnm");
>
>                                                       }
>                                                       if (jobj.has("supfildt")) {
>
>                                                           supfildt = jobj.getString("supfildt");
>
>                                                       }
>                                                       if (jobj.has("supprd")) {
>
>                                                           supprd = jobj.getString("supprd");
>
>                                                       }
>                                                       if (jobj.has("inv") && jobj.get("inv") instanceof JSONObject) {
>
>                                                           JSONObject jitemobj = jobj.getJSONObject("inv");
>
>                                                           double invValue = 0.0;
>
>                                                           String invoiceNum = "";
>
>                                                           String invType = "";
>
>                                                           String InvDate = "";
>
>                                                           String pos = "";
>
>                                                           String rev = "";
>
>                                                           String itcavl = "";
>                                                           String rsn = "";
>
>                                                           double diffprcnt = 0.00;
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("inum")) {
>
>                                                               invoiceNum = jitemobj.getString("inum");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("typ")) {
>
>                                                               invType = jitemobj.getString("typ");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("val")) {
>
>                                                               invValue = invValue + jitemobj.getDouble("val");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("pos")) {
>
>                                                               pos = jitemobj.getString("pos");
>
>                                                           } else {
>
>                                                               pos = "";
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("rev")) {
>
>                                                               rev = jitemobj.getString("rev");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("itcavl")) {
>
>                                                               itcavl = jitemobj.getString("itcavl");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("rsn")) {
>
>                                                               rsn = jitemobj.getString("rsn");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("diffprcnt")) {
>
>                                                               diffprcnt = diffprcnt + jitemobj.getDouble("diffprcnt");
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                           if (jitemobj.has("items")
>                                                                   && jitemobj.get("items") instanceof JSONArray) {
>
>                                                               JSONArray jitemdataarray = jitemobj
>                                                                       .getJSONArray("items");
>
>                                                               for (int j = 0; j < jitemdataarray.length(); j++) {
>
>                                                                   cess = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   txval = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   cgst = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   igst = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   sgst = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   rt = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   num = 0.00;
>
>                                                                   JSONObject jitemdataobjitemobj = jitemdataarray
>                                                                           .getJSONObject(j);
>
>                                                                   // JSONObject jitemdataobjitemobj =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobj.getJSONObject("itm_det");
>
>                                                                   // csamt =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("csamt");
>
>                                                                   // txval =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("txval");
>
>                                                                   // camt =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("camt");
>
>                                                                   // iamt =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("iamt");
>
>                                                                   // samt =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("samt");
>
>                                                                   // rt =
>                                                                   // jitemdataobjitemobj.getInt("rt");
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("num")) {
>
>                                                                       num = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("num");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("rt")) {
>
>                                                                       rt = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("rt");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("txval")) {
>
>                                                                       txval = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("txval");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("igst")) {
>
>                                                                       igst = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("igst");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("cgst")) {
>
>                                                                       cgst = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("cgst");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("sgst")) {
>
>                                                                       sgst = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("sgst");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   if (jitemdataobjitemobj.has("cess")) {
>
>                                                                       cess = jitemdataobjitemobj.getDouble("cess");
>
>                                                                   }
>
>                                                                   ObjData = new Object[] { ctin, trdnm, supfildt,
>                                                                           supprd, invoiceNum, invType, invValue, pos,
>                                                                           rev, itcavl, rsn, diffprcnt, num, rt, txval,
>                                                                           igst, cgst, sgst, cess };
>
>                                                                   listData.add(ObjData);
>
>                                                               }
>
>                                                           }
>
>                                                       }
>
>                                                   }
>                                               } 
>                                               } 
>                                           }
>                                       }
>                                   }
>                               }
>
>                               SXSSFWorkbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
>
>                               if (listData != null && listData.size() > 0) {
>                                   SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workBook
>                                           .createSheet(section.toUpperCase() + "Report");
>
>                                   Row r1 = sheet.createRow(0);
>
>                                   int rowCount = 1;
>
>                                   for (int rn = 0; rn < headers.length; rn++) {
>
>                                       r1.createCell(rn).setCellValue(headers[rn]);
>
>                                   }
>
>                                   for (Object[] data : listData) {
>
>                                       Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
>
>                                       for (int rn = 0; rn < data.length; rn++) {
>
>                                           if (data[rn] instanceof String) {
>
>                                               row.createCell(rn).setCellValue((String) data[rn]);
>
>                                           } else if (data[rn] instanceof Integer) {
>
>                                               row.createCell(rn).setCellValue((Integer) data[rn]);
>
>                                           } else if (data[rn] instanceof Double) {
>
>                                               row.createCell(rn).setCellValue((Double) data[rn]);
>
>                                           } else if (data[rn] instanceof BigDecimal) {
>
>                                               row.createCell(rn).setCellValue(String.format("%.2f", data[rn]));
>
>                                           }
>
>                                       }
>
>                                       rowCount++;
>
>                                   }
>
>                                   try (FileOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
>                                           gstrUtils.getPropertyValue("GSTR2B_FILES")+gstin + "_" + userId + "_" + period + "_" + section + "_" + recordsCount + "_GSTR2BFile.xlsx");) {
>
>                                       workBook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
>
>                                   } finally {
>
>                                       workBook.close();
>                                       workBook.dispose();
>
>                                       // renaming a file Start
>                                       File oldfile = new File(gstrUtils.getPropertyValue("GSTR2B_FILES") + fileName);
>                                       String beforeExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
>                                       String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
>                                       File newfile = new File(gstrUtils.getPropertyValue("GSTR2B_TEXT_FILES") + beforeExtension
>                                               + "-done" + fileExtension);
>
>                                       if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile)) {
>                                           LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "File renamed");
>                                       } else {
>                                           LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "Sorry! the file can't be renamed");
>                                       }
>                                       // renaming a file End
>
>                                   }
>
>                               }
>                           }
>
>                       }
>                   } else {
>                       LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "The file is not a text (.txt) file hence skipping");
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       } else {
>           LogWrapper.info(CronJobGstr2b.class, "No files found in the folder cronJobTextFiles");
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Is there a way in which I can read the jsonString line by line or get first object of jsonArray which is currently in string format and then keep on appending to excel line by line?

Comment: Depending on the JSON file size you have to increase the memory available to java. If you give java 2GB of RAM and the file is 3GB, then there is no way you can ever read the file completely

Comment: How do we increase the memory available to java?
from eclipse.ini file 
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m

Plus can the processing time be reduced by creating an excel of 1 row first and then keep on appending one one row in the same excel.